# How do I merge and repeat population cells in a data frame with existing data frame?

Tags: pandas, join, merge, append, concatenation

I have a data frame about drunk driving in the US. It lists all incidents by state and year. There are multiple entries per year. My separate population-size per state data frame has one entry per year. How do I add the population column from the population data frame to the drunk driving data frame and repeat it for multiple entries per year? Right now it's just adding the population data frame underneath the drunk driving data frame without merging them. I would appreciate anyone's help. Been stuck on this for a couple days.

I've tried multiple different ways using concat, merge, append, etc.

```
df = pd.concat([df, df_pops], sort=False)
df = pd.merge(df, df_pops)
```

I need the final data frame to looks like this:

```
STATE      MONTH YEAR FATALS DRUNK_DR POPULATION
Oregon     1     2017   1       1      4,146,600
Oregon     2     2017   0       1      4,146,600
Oregon     3     2017   1       2      4,146,600
...
```

Here's what I'm getting:

```
         STATE         MONTH    YEAR    FATALS  DRUNK_DR  POPULATION
5619    Oregon          1.0     2017    1.0      0.0        NaN
5620    Oregon          1.0     2017    1.0      0.0        NaN
5621    Oregon          1.0     2017    1.0      0.0        NaN
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
30      Oregon          NaN     2017    NaN      NaN       4,146,600
31      Oregon          NaN     2016    NaN      NaN       4,091,400
32      Oregon          NaN     2015    NaN      NaN       4,016,900
```

Comment: Thank you Brendan for fixing the formatting of the question. This is the first time I've posted and still learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merging is correct; you're just missing the syntax. I'd recommend reading the very helpful [pandas documentation on `merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'STATE': {0: 'Oregon', 1: 'Oregon', 2: 'Oregon'},
                    'MONTH': {0: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 1.0},
                    'YEAR': {0: 2017, 1: 2017, 2: 2017},
                    'FATALS': {0: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 1.0},
                    'DRUNK_DR': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0}})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'STATE': {0: 'Oregon', 1: 'Oregon', 2: 'Oregon'},
                    'YEAR': {0: 2017, 1: 2016, 2: 2015},
                    'POPULATION': {0: '4,146,600', 1: '4,091,400', 2: '4,016,900'}})

merged = df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on=['STATE','YEAR'], right_on=['STATE','YEAR'])
```

gives

```
    STATE  MONTH  YEAR  FATALS  DRUNK_DR POPULATION
0  Oregon    1.0  2017     1.0       0.0  4,146,600
1  Oregon    1.0  2017     1.0       0.0  4,146,600
2  Oregon    1.0  2017     1.0       0.0  4,146,600
```

Comment: Thanks. Just tried that and got this error message: ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

Comment: @pfistermiyagi It sounds like your `year` column is a string (object) in one dataframe, and an integer (int64) in another. You'll need to convert the datatypes to merge properly -- e.g., with `df1['YEAR'].astype(int)` (adapted for your own code).

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much. Although I had to convert to string first then int. df['YEAR'] = df['YEAR'].astype(str).astype(int)